# MVC Foolproof validation - Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, foolproof-validation

I am using `MVC Foolproof validation` in my application.
Scenario is I have a dropdownlist named CustomerType with the the following values

```
 Id     Name
 1      Student
 2      Non-Employed
 3      Employed
 4      SelfEmployed
```

and I have one more property in my viewmodel `public string CompanyAddress{ get; set; }`.My goal is to make CompanyAddress `required if` dropdownlist has values `3 or 4`

I have tried the following

```
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select status of the customer", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int? customerTypeID { get; set; }
    public SelectList customerTypeList { get; set; }

   [RequiredIf("IsCompanyAddressRequired", true, ErrorMessage = "please enter company address")]
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }


 public bool IsCompanyAddressRequired
    {
        get
        {
            if (customerTypeID == 3 || customerTypeID == 4)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

The above code is working properly on the server side but on the client side i'm getting the following error

```
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`
```

Validation is being referenced as follows

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/plugins/jQueryVal/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/plugins/jQueryVal/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/plugins/foolproofValidation/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/foolproofValidation/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js",
                    "~/plugins/foolproofValidation/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js"
                    ));
```

Comment: This cant work unless you generate an input for property `IsCompanyAddressRequired` in the view (and then you would need to dynamically update it based on the selected value in the dropdownlist. Insread, use a `[GreaterThan("customerTypeID", 2)]` and delete the `bool` property

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Here i am getting the error `Foolproof.GreaterThanAttribute` does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.

Comment: Sorry, getting confused with my own validation attributes :) - Let me check the docs (not even sure foolproof supports this)

Comment: Looks like it needs to be `[RequiredIf("customerTypeID", Operator.GreaterThan, 2, ErrorMessage = "..")]`

Comment: Thanks mate its working and please post the answer..:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your validation attribute could not work on the client on the client unless you were to generate a input (say) `<input name="IsCompanyAddressRequired" value="false" />` (or `value="true"` depending on the initial value of `customerTypeID`) and then dynamically update the value attribute using javascript when the dropdownlist value is changed.

Instead use

```
[RequiredIf("customerTypeID", Operator.GreaterThan, 2, ErrorMessage = "..")]
public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
```

and delete your `IsCompanyAddressRequired` property.